# Performing an SQL query in oxid

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oxid

I am fairly new to OXID.

I am trying to perform an SQL query by using OXID functions only.

The point is to check if $discount exists in oxVoucherSerie's table oxdiscount, and if it exists get the oxid from oxVoucherSerie that corresponds to that discount.

Sadly I cannot use plain MySQL and I am only allowed to use oxid functions. I have no idea how to do it.

```
    public function save_voucher($discount){
$o_voucherid         = oxNew("oxVoucherSerie");
$aWhere_discount['oxdiscount']    = $discount;
$sSql                       = $o_voucherid->buildSelectString($aWhere_discount);
$b_exists                   = $o_voucher->assignRecord($sSql);
}
```

This tells me if the discount exists. However, I have no idea to retrieve oxid from said discount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we might need to clarify some wording and variables first, because i'm not really sure what you are trying to achieve.

**voucher** - (also called "coupon") shop visitor can enter voucher/coupon code in basket to achieve a price reduction or a free product.
Vouchers are generated in Shop Settings -> coupon series

**discount** - general price reduction for some categories or articles, e.g. 10% for pet accessories.
Discounts can be configured in Shop Settings -> Discounts

---

okay, i updated my post.

your code works well, i just changed it a little bit. First the code and then the explanation:

```
$o_voucher = oxNew("oxVoucherSerie");
$aWhere_discount['oxdiscount'] = 25;
$sSql = $o_voucher->buildSelectString($aWhere_discount);
$o_voucher->assignRecord($sSql);
var_dump($o_voucher);
```

I replaced **$o_voucherid** with **$o_voucher** (without *id*)
`$o_voucher = oxNew("oxVoucherSerie");` gives you an oxVoucherSeries Object
`$o_voucher->assignRecord($sSql);` does not only tell you if voucher series with such discount exists, it also will load this voucher serie into **$o_voucher** , so you can access all the (not protedted) parameters of this voucher serie by using $o_voucher, e.g.:
`$o_voucher->getId()` or `$o_voucher->oxvoucherseries__oxid->value()` for getting its oxID or just `var_dump($o_voucher);` to see all the objects properties

By the way, if you are developing with OXID 4.9 you could use this module: https://marat.ws/direct-access-to-oxid-framework-functions/ for quick evaluating and debugging you code.
just copy-paste the code from above into the textarea and hit the button

Comment: Yes. It is a module that combines both. $discount is the amount to be discounted. A function adds the discount to the oxvoucherseries if this discount doesnt previously exist. Then a new function should check if a given voucher apply a discount. In order to see if this discount exists I need to retrieve the oxid of the oxvoucherseries and in order to get the correct oxid I have to compare it to the $discount.